# Dart Editor: "unused import" errors

Tags: dart, dart-editor

For a project, I'm importing a library but I don't use any of the classes in it directly. The goal is to fetch a `ClassMirror` at runtime to create an instance from it. So I have something like:

```dart
import 'controllers.dart';

main() {
    ClassMirror controller = getClassFromString(libraryName: 'deck_app', className: 'HomeController');
    InstanceMirror instance = controller.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []);
    instance.reflectee.sayHey();
}
```

This gives me an "unused import" error. Idk if this is to be considered a bug. So I'm asking you: do you think this is to be considered as a bug? If not, is there a way I could suppress unused import errors?

What's weird is I thought Dart would tree-shake the source and remove the unused import's code, but it does not. The library is properly imported and available.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Dart would tree-shake'? Tree shaking is only done by dart2js with minification?

Comment: Ah ok. I thought this kind of thing also worked with the Dart VM (not loading useless stuff into memory).

Comment: dart2js has a mode where it outputs Dart code instead of JavaScript code. AFAIK this is in early stage.

Comment: Does the warning go away if you use symbols instead of Strings. i.e. #deck_app and #HomeController?  Also - there is an experimental class to give you some control over tree shaking called [MirrorsUsed](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorsUsed.html).

Answer (score 1):

The unused import is just a conclusion from the static analyzer. You can ignore it or add a dummy statement to silence the analyzer. This has no effect when you run the application.